# What does System.ServiceModel.Clientbase.Open() do?

Tags: c#, wcf

What does System.ServiceModel.Clientbase.Open() do? I've never used it but just came across it in some code. Can it throw exceptions? If Close() is not called is it a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a proxy for a WCF service the proxy is effectively ClientBase

Example from my app:

```
public class DataClient : ClientBase<Classes.IDataService>, Classes.IDataService
{
    public DataClient(string connectToHost)
        : base(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport)
            {
                PortSharingEnabled = true,
                Security = new NetTcpSecurity()
                {
                    Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity()
                    {
                        ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows
                    }
                }
            },
            new EndpointAddress(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:5555/MyService",connectToHost)))
    { }

    #region IDataService Members

    public Classes.Folder GetFolder(string entryID)
    {
        return Channel.GetFolder(entryID);
    }

    public Classes.IItem GetItem(string entryID)
    {
        return Channel.GetItem(entryID);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**EDIT**
Per your request I googled a bit and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575279.aspx):

> Implements ICommunicationObject.Open()

This led to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195524.aspx):

> CommunicationException
>
> The ICommunicationObject was unable to
>   be opened and has entered the Faulted
>   state.
>
> TimeoutException
>
> The default open timeout elapsed
>   before the ICommunicationObject was
>   able to enter the Opened state and has
>   entered the Faulted state.

Also, per experience and what I've come across on the 'net not closing your clients can cause various forms of strangeness to occur and is thus generally considered "[A Bad Thing](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/Bad-Thing.html)".

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I think I've got that much down. So what does System.ServiceModel.Clientbase.Open() do? Can it throw exceptions? If Close() is not called is it a problem? If the above answers those questions, I didn't follow it; would you mind expanding?

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked that it implements ICommunicationObject which gives a little bit more information about the Open() method. It can throw a CommunicationException and TimeoutException. From what I can tell, all calling Open does is set a flag and make the object unconfigurable so I'm not seeing any reason, under normal circumstances, to explicitly call Open before calling a method of a web service.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this article:

> Best Practice: Always open WCF client proxy explicitly when it is shared 
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wenlong/2007/10/25/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared/

That states in the end:

> If you don’t call the “Open” method first, the proxy would be opened internally when the first call is made on the proxy. This is called auto-open.
>
> Why? When the first message is sent through the auto-opened proxy, it will cause the proxy to be opened automatically. You can use .NET Reflector to open the method System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call and see the following code:

```
if (!this.explicitlyOpened)
{
   this.EnsureDisplayUI();
   this.EnsureOpened(rpc.TimeoutHelper.RemainingTime());
}
```

> When you drill down into EnsureOpened, you will see that it calls CallOnceManager.CallOnce. For non-first calls, you would hit SyncWait.Wait which waits for the first request to complete. This mechanism is to ensure that all requests wait for the proxy to be opened and it also ensures the correct execution order. Thus all requests are serialized into a single execution sequence until all requests are drained out from the queue. This is not a desired behavior in most cases.
>
> To avoid such “serializing” artifact, the best practice is to open the proxy explicitly as above. Once you get to this point, you will be able to share the same proxy object among multiple threads.