# Change WebService Endpoint from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I'm really new to .NET and I have come to a roadblock (I guess).

I have a project that needs changing one address for another service we use, this address changed from HTTP to HTTPS.

My question is, for this change, do I need to change the code of the method that invokes the request, so I load the certificate in there, or do I just change the endpoint config?

I've tried the endpoint config security binding from `None` to `TransportWithMessageCredential`, also loading the certificate to the machine repository, but I'm not sure how do I specify what certificate I want to send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using `BasicHttpBinding` right now, and need to change from a HTTP endpoint to a HTTPS endpoint that requires validation through X509 certificate. I'm assuming you're using C#.

If you're using any version of .NET Framework older than **4.5**, you can do:

```cs
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
```

If you are using .NET Framework 4.5 or newer version, you can do like this:

```cs
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

Assuming you've imported the WebService definition deriving from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase` (like when you right-click the project in Visual Studio and choose Add > Service Reference), you can do something like this:

```cs
var address = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);
var wsClient = new ServiceReference1.YourServiceClient(binding, address);
// x509Cert is a variable of type 'X509Certificate2'.
wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

// Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49303859/
wsClient.Open();
wsClient.CallTheService();
wsClient.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you! this was the answer